# Convert `ï¿½` string to diamond question mark symbol (�) in R

Tags: r, google-sheets-api

I have been using the `googlesheets` package to upload and download data from a websheet. Previously, it had been downloading strings with non-ASCII symbols with the icon �. Now, for no apparent reason, it has started downloading them with the following string: `ï¿½`. How can I convert `ï¿½` to the diamond questionmark symbol (�)?

Comment: You could clean it up with `gsub` or `chartr`, but there's likely an underlying encoding issue that would be the better thing to fix

Comment: @alistaire an example of how to clean this up with gsub would be awesome!

Comment: Iterate the `gsub` call across any character (and factor?) columns, e.g. `df[sapply(df, is.character)] <- lapply(df[sapply(df, is.character)], function(x){gsub('ï¿½', '�', x)})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you have an encoding problem. I suspect that the raw data is encoded in UTF-8, but at some point it is getting treated as Windows-1252.

This is what happens when the encoding is wrongly marked as Windows-1252, and then converted to UTF-8:

```
x <- "Here is a raw string: � is getting converted to ï¿½"
(y <- iconv(x, "WINDOWS-1252", "UTF-8"))
#> [1] "Here is a raw string: ï¿½ is getting converted to Ã¯Â¿Â½"
```

You can fix the encoding error by converting from UTF-8 to Windows-1252, then marking the result as UTF-8:

```
z <- iconv(y, "UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1252")
Encoding(z) <- "UTF-8"
print(z)
#> [1] "Here is a raw string: � is getting converted to ï¿½"
```

*Note: The code will still work on MacOS and Linux if you leave out the `Encoding(z) <- "UTF-8"` line, but it will break on Windows. If you leave out that line then `z` will have "unknown" encoding, which gets interpreted as "UTF-8" on Linux and MacOS but not on Windows.*

### Windows Users

If you're using Windows, then the fix could be much simpler. If your data has `"unknown"` encoding, then on MacOS and Linux it will (correctly) be interpreted as UTF-8, but on Windows it will be interpreted using your native encoding, usually Windows-1252. If you are on Windows, then something like the following happens:

```
x <- "Here is a raw string: � is getting converted to ï¿½"
y <- x
Encoding(y) <- "unknown"
print(y)
#> [1] "Here is a raw string: ï¿½ is getting converted to Ã¯Â¿Â½"
```

You can fix this as follows:

```
z <- y
Encoding(z) <- "UTF-8"
print(z)
#> [1] "Here is a raw string: � is getting converted to ï¿½"
```